# Creating dynamic dropdown lists

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create dynamic select lists. For example: I have 5 students in my db. My goal is to create 5 selects ,and in every select all students which are in database. So if user inserts a 6th student in the database, the page should display 6 selects, and in every select names of 6 students.

I've tried with this code, but it only creates 1 select, containing 4 students(the first one from the db is missing).

The Code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","novi-studomat");
$exe="SELECT * FROM kolegij WHERE id_student='$id_student'";
$i=1;
$execute=mysqli_query($con,$exe);
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($execute))
{
echo '<select name=student'.$i.'>';
echo '<option value="-1" >Choose student</option> <br/>';
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($execute))
{
    echo '<option value='.$res["id_student"].'>'.$res["name"].'</option> <br/>';
}
echo '</select>';
$i++;
}
```

Comment: as andrewsi says, you have two while but you need to remove the inner one not the outer.

Comment: You're probably better off running a single while loop to go through the results from the database, and to use that to generate the SQL for the `<option>`s. Then run a second loop to generate the `<select>`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I just needed to insert vars $exe and $execute inside for loop, so after every  iteration $result is refreshed,otherwise it just prints options in first select...

CODE:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","novi-studomat");
$exe="SELECT * FROM kolegij WHERE id_student='$id_student'";

$execute=mysqli_query($con,$exe);
$select = '';

for($j = 0; $j < mysqli_num_rows($execute); $j++) 
{
    $exe="SELECT * FROM kolegij WHERE id_student='$id_student'";
    $execute=mysqli_query($con,$exe);

    $select .= '<select name=student' . $j . '>';
    $select .= '<option value="-1" >Choose student</option> <br/>';
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) 
    {
         $select .= '<option value=' . $res["id_student"].'>' .   $res["name"] . '</option>';
    }
    $select .= '</select>';
}
echo $select;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","novi-studomat");
$exe="SELECT * FROM kolegij WHERE id_student='$id_student'";

$i=1;
$execute=mysqli_query($con,$exe);
$select = '';
for($j = 0; $j < mysqli_num_rows($execute); $j++) {
    $select .= '<select name=student' . $j . '>';
    $select .= '<option value="-1" >Choose student</option> <br/>';
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) {
        $select .= '<option value=' . $res["id_student"].'>' .   $res["name"] . '</option>';
        $i++;
    }
    $select .= '</select>';
}
echo $select;
```

## UPDATE

inside the while

```
$select = '<select name=student' . $j . '>';
$select .= '<option value=' . $res["id_student"].'>' .   $res["name"] .
```

change this lines by this other

```
$select = '<select name="student' . $j . '">';
$select .= '<option value="' . $res["id_student"]."'>' .   $res["name"] .
```

we missed the double quotes for value and in select name

Comment: That will create the right number of selects, but each will just have one student in.

Comment: Indeed it will. Have a +1.

Comment: It created proper number of selects, but only first select contains all 5 students, rest of the selects only contain value -1??? Any ideas?

Comment: Try it but leave the quotes